# ViewModel and Activity using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, persistence, viewmodel

How do I get a variable from an edit text into a save variable in viewmodel?
I want to get the below variable into my Viewmodel from MainActivity
`val age = (binding.age.text.toString()).toInt()`
I think I have to have a saved handle state in the activity and then a get() in the view model. I was hoping to get some pointers. Or am I missing the point and should have it in my mainactivity with OnResume?

I am preforming the below steps in my veiwmodel which work yet upon rotation the age is not saved:

````
private const val TAG = "age"
//const val age = "age"

class hrViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {


    fun update(ageinput: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG,"age", Exception())
        val maxhr = 220 - ageinput
        return maxhr
    }
    fun concatenate(vararg digits: Int): String {
        return digits.joinToString(separator = " - ", transform = Int::toString)
    }
    fun target(agein: Int): String {
        val bank = update(agein)
        val high = bank * .5
        val low = bank * .85
        return concatenate(high.toInt(), low.toInt())

    }
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by “save variable”? It’s not clear what you’re trying to do.

Comment: In my UI I have a edit text called age I wanted save the age to ViewModel since both functions inside viewmodel use the age int. I can't seem to get it into Viewmodel to keep the variable without piping it into a function call. IE have update(int:age). I hope that makes sense

Comment: I am new to kotlin so I think it is the override fun onresume() in the main that holds the user input during a transition?

Comment: Delete the `const val age` line, since that doesn’t make sense. `age` shouldn't be a String. You can put a property inside your class `var age: Int = 0` with 0 replaced with whatever you want the initial value to be. Then your other class can directly change it, such as by calling `viewModel.age = 40`

Comment: So are you saying to use a binder? @Tenfour04 for example I am retrieving the age from a edit text have it = in MainActivity and then in ViewModel have binding.age? I guess my question is how do I get a variable from MainActivity that is not through a funciton into VeiwModel

Comment: Just a property. I don’t know what a binder is. Functions and properties are the only two ways two classes can directly interact with each other. The Activity must proactively pass its data to ViewModel because a ViewModel cannot hold a reference to an Activity without leaking memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `SavedStateHandle` the usual way is like this:

```
val age = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Int>("age", 0) // or whatever default

fun setAge(age: Int) {
    savedStateHandle["age"] = age
}
```

That way you set the *age* value through that function, which stores it in the `SavedStateHandle`, and that value propagates through to the `LiveData` where you can read it with `age.value`, or `observe` it as normal. So you only need to set it once.

---

If you have any internal functions that need to read that value, just do

```
// a rare case where !! can make sense, since you -know- it won't be null
// since it has a default value
val currentAge = age.value!!
// do stuff with currentAge
```

Or you could follow the same reactive pattern, and make it so that when `age` updates, your other properties automatically do too, e.g.

```
val maxHr: LiveData<Int> = age.map { age -> 220 - age }
```

You can chain things like this so you keep all your values updated automatically, just by laying out the rules about what happens when something else changes.

---

To update that `age` value, just call `setAge`. Since you're trying to store the contents of your `EditText`, you need to update the `ViewModel` whenever those contents change. You can do that with a `TextWatcher` - the `androidx.core-ktx` libraries have some nice functions for that, so you can just implement the callback you need:

```
binding.age.doAfterTextChanged { it?.toString()?.toIntOrNull()?.run(model::setAge) }
```

So now, whenever the text contents change, it attempts to parse them as an `Int` and calls `setAge` on the VM with the result.

---

And since these are `LiveData` objects, your UI can `observe` them and display stuff whenever it updates, including when your `Fragment` is first connected. So if you observe that `age` `LiveData`, you can display it in your text box, and when the fragment is created it'll automatically display the current info

```
// in the fragment, in onViewCreated is best since you need the viewLifecycleOwner
model.age.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { age ->
    ageText = age.toString()
    if (binding.age.text.toString() != ageText) binding.age.setText(ageText)
}
```

That check there is to avoid updating the `EditText` when it's already showing that value. That's important because remember, we have a `TextWatcher` that updates `age` whenever the `EditText`'s contents are changed. But since updating `age` triggers the observer, and that updates the contents of the `EditText`... you could have an infinite circular loop!

So this is one approach to breaking that loop. You could also call `distinctUntilChanged()` on your `LiveData` to get one that doesn't update (or push a value to observers) if the new value is the current one:

```
val age = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Int>("age", 0).distinctUntilChanged()
```

---

This is all a little awkward because `EditText`s and other Android view widgets already maintain their own state (like the entered text) - but this is how you would *push* the state in the `ViewModel` to the UI, to make it display what the VM says it should (which is [a recommended approach these days](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders)). That also enables you to e.g. load stored state (say getting data from a database or something) and letting the UI automatically display it, and it Just Works